# Mule throttling on a backend service

Tags: activemq-classic, mule, throttling

I have a back end service that I need to throttle access to.  I'm trying to use the approach described here: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/synchronous-and-asynchronous-throttling-2/

I started with a simple pass through flow that receives a SOAP request and forwards it.  When I hit this using the SOAPUI utility, I get the expected response in a second or two.

```
<http:connector name="httpConnector" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1" maxBufferSize="100" />
</http:connector>

<jms:activemq-connector name="amqConnector" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" specification="1.1" doc:name="AMQ" />

<flow name="Flow1" processingStrategy="synchronous" doc:name="Flow1">

    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" 
        host="localhost" port="8088" path="test" doc:name="HTTP" 
        mimeType="text/xml" encoding="UTF-8" connector-ref="httpConnector"/>

    <http:outbound-endpoint
        address="http://dnbdirect-api.dnb.com/DnBAPI-11"
        exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP" mimeType="text/xml"/>
</flow>
```

If I then move the outbound call to a separate flow and add in the request-reply block, the behavior changes.  I get no response back (nor do I get the "After queue" message from the logger) and SOAPUI eventually times out.

```
<http:connector name="httpConnector" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1" maxBufferSize="100" />
</http:connector>

<jms:activemq-connector name="amqConnector" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" specification="1.1" doc:name="AMQ" />

<flow name="Flow1" processingStrategy="synchronous" doc:name="Flow1">

    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" 
        host="localhost" port="8088" path="test" doc:name="HTTP" 
        mimeType="text/xml" encoding="UTF-8" connector-ref="httpConnector"/>

    <message-properties-transformer  doc:name="Message Properties">
        <add-message-property key="AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY" value="5000"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>

    <logger message="Before queue" level="INFO"/>

    <request-reply>
        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="request" connector-ref="amqConnector"></jms:outbound-endpoint>
        <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="response" connector-ref="amqConnector"></jms:inbound-endpoint>
    </request-reply>  

    <logger message="After queue" level="INFO"/>
</flow>

<flow name="flow2" doc:name="Flow2">

    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="request" connector-ref="amqConnector" doc:name="JMS"/>

    <http:outbound-endpoint 
        address="http://dnbdirect-api.dnb.com/DnBAPI-11" 
        exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP" mimeType="text/xml" />
</flow>
```

The throttling behavior works as I see the delays if I pull out the call to the back end service.  But I can't get it to work with the service call there.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try adding a logger after the http:outbound in your flow2 and check what is the payload.

Comment: I have and it seems to be correct.  I can't put it in this comment due to length (I'm not that experienced with StackOverflow)...is the normal thing to add it into the original message to display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the message's payload will be "ArrayList" after "request-reply".
so i add a java component to split it, then the result will be corrected.

```
@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    MuleMessage message = eventContext.getMessage();

    //int groupSize = message.getCorrelationGroupSize();
    //System.out.println("############# correlationGroupSize: " + groupSize);

    Object payload = message.getPayload();
    if (payload != null && payload instanceof ArrayList) {
        //message.setPayload(((ArrayList)payload).get(0));
        return ((ArrayList)payload).get(0);
    }

    return message.getPayload();
}
```

the completed flow is:

```
    <message-properties-transformer  doc:name="Message Properties">
        <add-message-property key="AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY" value="10000"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>

    <request-reply storePrefix="mainFlow">
        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="request" connector-ref="amqConnector" doc:name="JMS"></jms:outbound-endpoint>
        <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="response" connector-ref="amqConnector" doc:name="JMS"></jms:inbound-endpoint>
    </request-reply>
    <component class="com.neusoft.fx.JmsMessageTransformer" doc:name="Java"/>
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Set Content Type">
        <delete-message-property key="Content-type" />
        <add-message-property key="Content-Type" value="text/xml"/>
    </message-properties-transformer> 
    <logger message="----- LOGGER ----- after #[groovy:message.toString()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following before the HTTP outbound endpoint in flow2:

```
<copy-properties propertyName="MULE_*"/>
```

Comment: It worked for me with that. Can you show your new configuration with that change?

Comment: I stand partially corrected.  The flow is still not succeeding...i.e., it is not giving me the result I expect, but the behavior has changed with that addition.  I'm now getting to the "After queue" logging without a timeout.  The resulting payload doesn't look like I expect, i.e., like it does without using the queue.  Perhaps the passage through the queue is altering the format of the information?  Anyway, to address your request, how does one post a subsequent configuration since they won't fit in a comment?  Do you have to alter the original message?

Comment: I'll add that I don't believe the approach on Mule's site actually works for throttling.  However, this has now become a learning experience.